# If I don't log in right away on my 14.04 LTS system, the login hangs

Tags: login-screen

My newly dual booting system is working great with this one annoyance scenario:

1. I boot the system, but don't touch anything.
2. The screen eventually goes dark.
3. I touch a key and get the login screen.
4. I enter my password and hit enter.
5. The login screen disappears, but I never get the desktop.  It just hangs.

I am able to ssh in and reboot the system.  If I log in promptly then it's fine.

I'd settle for an answer telling me how to make the power saver never kick in and make the login screen go dark.  Or, a fix for the root cause.

More info:
It's stock Ubuntu 14.04 so I assume it's Unity. Graphics are "Gallium 0.4 on AMD CEDAR" according to System Settings/Details.

Logs will be posted next time it happens.

***Update - this hasn't happened since I posted the bounty.

Comment: are you using gdm or lightdm? what happens if you login to one of the alternate shells (ctrl+alt+F1)? If you can log on via the shell, can you kill the greeter, and respawn it? If you can, does the same event occur?

Comment: Lightdm.  When this happens, I can log in via ssh.  I tried to restart lightdm with "sudo service lightdm restart" from ssh, but I just got a black screen with blinking cursor.  I'll try logging in to one of the alternate shells.

Comment: im not asking about ssh, its a separate factor that only complicates the issue.

Comment: What is the correct command to kill the greeter and respawn it?

Comment: sudo service lightdm restart should be fine. is that not working? you could try sudo pkill lightdm && sudo lightdm could work. sudo kill -1 <PID>. There are many good ways to kill something in linux. So, you are running in an alternate shell ok? (any problems there?)

What Desktop Environment are you using? (Unity, mate, gnome... something else?) Do you have integrated graphics or a graphics card? (what kind of GPU?)

Comment: It's stock Ubuntu 14.04 so I assume it's Unity.  Graphics are "Gallium 0.4 on AMD CEDAR" according to System Settings/Details.

Comment: You may want to update your question with the additional information you have provided. can you show us the contents of /var/log/ligthdm/*.log files? Also /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Comment: Great suggestion, I will do that.

Comment: @j0h If I may suggest, `pkill lightdm && sudo service lightdm start` should be more appropriate

Comment: Have you tried changing the greeter (aka the login screen ) ? There's alternatives I use - gdm, lightdm-gtk-greeter, lightdm-webkit-greeter.

Comment: @OrganicMarble There is a graphical tool for checking the logs: from the dash search for `Log Viewer`

Comment: I am not sure if I got it right that the error occurs if the machine suspends before logging in (sorry if it just turns the screen off and I got that wrong), but if that is the case and you want to entirely disable suspending to work around this issue, I can provide you this [link] to the answer on my question about how to disable suspending. No idea if that helps you, but suggesting it does not hurt ;-)

Comment: Yes, I would be delighted to stop it from suspending. Please provide the link!

Answer (score -1):

I was also on the Same Boat when I had 14.04 Now I am on Velvet !

Here is the solution script that I has worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
echo Install BleachBit
echo
apt-get install bleachbit -y
echo
echo Clean
echo
apt-get autoclean
apt-get clean
echo
echo Update & Upgrade
echo
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
echo
echo
echo BleachBit Cleaning
echo
bleachbit -c adobe_reader.*
bleachbit -c apt.*
bleachbit -c chromium.*
bleachbit -c deepscan.*
bleachbit -c epiphany.*
bleachbit -c evolution.*
bleachbit -c filezilla.*
bleachbit -c firefox.*
bleachbit -c google_chrome.*
bleachbit -c kde.*
bleachbit -c java.*
bleachbit -c system.cache
bleachbit -c system.clipboard
bleachbit -c system.custom
bleachbit -c system.desktop_entry
bleachbit -c system.localizations
bleachbit -c system.memory
bleachbit -c system.recent_documents
bleachbit -c system.rotated_logs
bleachbit -c system.tmp
bleachbit -c system.trash
bleachbit -c opera.*
bleachbit -c thumbnails.*
bleachbit -c transmission.*
bleachbit -c x11.*
bleachbit -c vlc.*
bleachbit -c wine.*
echo 
echo Clean Up
echo
apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
echo
echo BleachBit ReBleach System
echo
bleachbit -c system.cache
bleachbit -c system.clipboard
bleachbit -c system.custom
bleachbit -c system.desktop_entry
bleachbit -c system.localizations
bleachbit -c system.memory
bleachbit -c system.recent_documents
bleachbit -c system.rotated_logs
bleachbit -c system.tmp
bleachbit -c system.trash
echo
echo Processes Complete
echo
```

Comment: I am not a fan of bleachbit.  Thanks though.